# How to get generated tokens in T5 training_step for using user-defined metrics?

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, pytorch-lightning

I am fine-tuning T5 for question answering generation and want to add additional measures (e.g., BLEU, ROUGE) for the generated answers, in addition to the loss function.

For that, I believe it would be necessary to obtain the generated tokens (answers) at each training_step. However, after reading the source code, I still have no clue how to add that.

Below I leave an excerpt of my code. I can extract the `output.loss` and `output.logits`, but I didn't find a way to get the generated tokens to use additional evaluation metrics.

Thanks in advance.

```
class MyQAModel(pl.LightningModule):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.model = T5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME, return_dict=True)

  def forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, labels=None):
    output = self.model(
        input_ids, 
        attention_mask=attention_mask,
        labels=labels)

    return output.loss, output.logits

  def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    input_ids = batch['input_ids']
    attention_mask=batch['attention_mask']
    labels = batch['labels']
    loss, outputs = self(input_ids, attention_mask, labels)
    self.log("train_loss", loss, prog_bar=True, logger=True)
    return {"loss": loss, "predictions":outputs, "labels": labels}
    
    ...
    (code continues...)
    ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain predicted tokens from `output.logits` [batch, seq_len, vocab_size] using `torch.argmax(output.logits, dim=-1)` [batch, seq_len]. Then, to decode the generated sentence from a batch of token ids, run

```py
generated_sentences = []
for predicted_token_ids in torch.argmax(output.logits, dim=-1):
    generated_sentences.append(tokenizer.decode(predicted_token_ids))

# For getting original sentences
original_sentences = []
for sent_ids in input_ids:
    original_sentences.append(tokenizer.decode(sent_ids))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However, I still have two related questions that I would like to clarify, if possible. What exactly is the purpose (and effect) of passing `output.logits` into `torch.argmax`? `torch.argmax` seems to only produce the predicted token ids. Are we supposed to use `tokenizer.decode(torch.argmax(output.logits, dim=-1))` to get the predicted tokens?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Once you get the generated string from `tokenizer.decode()`, you can compute those automatic metrics, e.g., BLEU, with the original sentence from `tokenizer.decode(input_ids)`. You will need to decode sentences one by one from the batch.

Comment: joe32140 can you update your answer for me to consider it correct?

Comment: sure! Please let me know if I have bugs since I did not actually run the code.

Comment: I have tested it already. Your code runs well! Can you just explain what exactly `torch.argmax` does in this case? How does it convert the negative values into 
token ids?

Comment: Logits will be passed to the softmax layer to get the probability distribution of predicted tokens so that you can compute cross entropy loss where this operation is embedded in the CrossEntropy function. If we just want to get the top 1 token with the highest probability, it's equivalent to just picking the token id with the highest logit values.